# Calculating average time (in days) between customer first and second order on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out the avg days it takes for a customer to repeat purchase.

Here is what I have

```
  Email_address, 
  Order_name, 
  Date, 
  Order_number,
  lead(date) over (partition by email_address order by Order_number) next_order_date,
  lead(Order_number) over (partition by email_address order by Order_number) next_order_number
 FROM `dbOrders` 
Group by 1,2,3,4
```

It's returning this

```
 [
  {
    "Email_address": "email@test.com",
    "Order_name": "#1234",
    "Date": "2019-11-08 00:18:00 UTC",
    "Order_number": "1",
    "next_order_date": "2019-11-28 20:54:00 UTC",
    "next_order_number": "2"
  },
```

I want to now get the average days between all first and second purchases, then second and third et

Sample data set

`|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     Email_address   |     Order_name   |  Order_number    |        Date      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    test@test.com    |         364      |         1        |    2019-08-11    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    test@test.com    |         366      |         2        |    2019-08-29    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     j@test.com      |         495      |         1        |    2019-09-04    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     j@test.com      |         564      |         2        |    2019-10-04    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|`

I want to find the avg time difference between the orders of both customers.
test@test.com = 18 days
j@test.com = 30 days

Average = 24 days

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking for an aggregation query:

```
select seqnum,
       avg(date_diff(date, next_date, day)) as avg_days_to_next_order
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email_address order by date) as seqnum,
             lead(date) over (partition by email_address order by date) as next-date
      from `dbOrders`  o
     ) o
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: It's returning this errorSyntax error: Unexpected keyword PARTITION